# Return substring if present in a string and match with case insensitive python

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to return a substring if is present in a string, with case insensitive.

So an example would be, I want to return the string "apple" even when the sentence is "Apple is cool" or "I like APPLE" or "I like apples"

What I have so far is this:

```
df_word_list = pd.DataFrame({'word':  ['apple','cool']})
df= pd.DataFrame({'sentence':  ['"Apple is cool","I like APPLE","I like apples"]})

words = [x for x in df_word_list['word'].tolist() if x in str(df['sentence'][i])]
```

This gives me the returned words, but it's case sensitive, anyone knows how to turn it into case insensitive?

I would like the final output to be

1. apple, cool
2. apple
3. 

Row 3 is empty because it has an "s" ("apples" instead of
"apple")

df_words_list is the dataframe of words that I want to identify. df is the dataframe that contains the sentences.

Comment: It would help you get answers faster if you specify the programming language in your tags. But generally, you can use regular express with `/words_to_match/i` to match against strings with case insensitivity.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) **TL;DR**: none.

Comment: I am using python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.sentence.str.lower().str.split().apply(lambda l: ", ".join([x for x in l if x in df_word_list["word"].values]))
```

result is `pandas.Series` of strings

```
0    apple, cool
1          apple
2              
Name: sentence, dtype: object
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you so much!

Comment: I have follow-up question. Apologies for this but would really appreciate it if you could help with this too. I am encountering instances where there is duplicate words in each row, is there a way only show 1 unique word if there are duplicates. 
Currently is show
1. apple apple
2. cool
3.
Ideally it should be
1. apple
2. cool
3.

Comment: just put the list comprehension inside `set( )`

Comment: so like this
set(df.sentence.str.lower().str.split().apply(lambda l: ", ".join([x for x in l if x in df_word_list["word"].values])))

Comment: no, like this
`df.sentence.str.lower().str.split().apply(lambda l: ", ".join(set([x for x in l if x in df_word_list["word"].values])))`